# FormData append json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I could not do new FormData or insert a json sequence

my Json data:

```
var data = {
        status: "COMPLETE",
        personName: $('#full_name').val(),
        personPhone: $('#phone_number').cleanVal(),
        personEmail: $('#e_mail').val(),
        referanceFullname: $('#person_full_name').val(),
        referancePhone: $('#person_phone_number').cleanVal(),
        referanceEmail: $('#person_e_mail').val()
      };
```

How do I attach this to new FormData?

Comment: Why do you need FormData?

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @hurricane my form have 2 disable input. I try serializeArray but not take disable inputs value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `append` to add new data. Checkout MDN about [`formData` `append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

```
var fd = new FormData();

var data = {
        status: "COMPLETE",
        personName: $('#full_name').val(),
        personPhone: $('#phone_number').cleanVal(),
        personEmail: $('#e_mail').val(),
        referanceFullname: $('#person_full_name').val(),
        referancePhone: $('#person_phone_number').cleanVal(),
        referanceEmail: $('#person_e_mail').val()
};


$.each(data, function(key, value){
  fd.append(key, value);
})
```

Comment: Yes, this code is better. It worked like I wanted. Thx

Comment: Okay if there nested object ?  data ={ first_name: 'Tom'}  ?

Answer (score 0):

Found one: https://github.com/therealparmesh/object-to-formdata/

`object-to-formdata` is a convenient JavaScript function that converts an object to a FormData instance.

Comment: But this one is for Typescript. Is there any plugin for javascript?

Answer (score -1):

You can do by this code.

```
 var data = new FormData();
 data.append("status", "COMPLETE");
 data.append("personName", $('#full_name').val());
 data.append("personPhone", $('#phone_number').cleanVal());
 data.append("personEmail", $('#e_mail').val());
 data.append("referanceFullname", $('#person_full_name').val());
 data.append("referancePhone", $('#person_phone_number').cleanVal());
 data.append("referanceEmail", $('#person_e_mail').val());

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            processData: true,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {                    
            },
            success: function (data) {                    
            },
});
```